# How to force draw a new signature for each signature field - Soap API

Tags: docusignapi

We have set up an integration with DocuSign through Soap API. We need to be able to force customer's to draw a new signature for each signature field.
In the regular DocuSign it was doable when manually creating a new envelope and ticking the "Draw a new signature for each signature or initial field" checkbox under Advanced Settings. 
How we can get the same result with Soap API when creating a new envelope.

Answer (score 0):

It's an account setting, as you have identified. It is not an api setting.